# How can I calculate a partial derivative by hand in python

Tags: python, derivative

I've been trying for days to calculate a partial derivative in python, including several other posts on here!

I think I'm a step closer to figuring out what I need to do but I'm unsure how to implement a manual partial differentiation of the following formula in python.

```
aj(x) = cj * product (xi, si)
```

Which calculates the probability of a biochemical reaction firing in a system of multiple reactions. The partial differentiation needs to be with respect to `xi` which is an array of discrete molecule numbers for each molecular species in the model called `popul_num`.

Where `product (xi, si)` is the product of the binomial coefficient, for the array containing discrete molecule numbers and a second array `LHS` that contains the ratios of molecules in each reaction (`si`).

So over all my derivation equation should be something like: `bj(x) = daj(x)/d(xi)`. 
I have written the following function that calculates aj(x) for each reaction and returns an array:

```
import numpy
import scipy

def propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate):
    propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))
    for row in range(len(LHS)):
            a = stoch_rate[row]     
            for i in range(len(popul_num)):
                if (popul_num[i] >= LHS[row, i]):       
                    binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])
                    aj = a*binom_rxn
                else:
                    aj = 0
                    break
            propensity[row] = aj    
return propensity
```

where `stoch_rate` is an array containg the rate of each reaction.

I tried using scipys `misc.derivation` method, but my supervisor has since told me to do it by hand and I'm not sure how to implement that in python.
Its maybe a bit more a maths question, and if anyone knows a more appropriate place for me to ask or has any good links to online resources for me to read, please point me towards it!

Cheers

Comment: Maybe [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) is what you need.

Comment: If you are using Python how is that doing it by hand? It seems that your supervisor wants you to grapple with the computation yourself. Seems like basic Calc III.